# Bootstrap: highlight modified input text?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

Is there a built-in way (or a plugin) which highlights `input` elements which have been modified? As long as the input does not have its original value, the input would be highlighted in some way (e.g. orange border). One could mark all inputs as "unmodified" using JavaScript (e.g., called by my "Save Changes" button).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a `change` event listener for each `input` element to add a class.

---

```js
(function() {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    var initialValue = inputs[i].value;

    inputs[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
      if (initialValue !== this.value) {
        this.classList.add("changed");
      } else {
        this.classList.remove("changed");
      }
    });
  }
})();
```

```css
.changed {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" value="Initial Value">
  <input type="text" value="Initial Value">
  <button type="submit">
    Save Changes
  </button>
</form>
```

---

If you want to highlight it after submit you can use this class as a selector to add another one with the desired styling.

Comment: I hoped for something built-in, but that will do.

Comment: @Ricky thanks! Curious, how would we have this take effect without the need to exit the input field?

Comment: @jason3w Instead of using the `change` event type, use `input`:  `inputs[i].addEventListener("input", function() { ... })`

Comment: thanks, @Ricky for writing back. I tried your suggestion, however, I still have to remove focus from the input for it to trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You could use AngularJS:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<style>
    .red {
        color:red;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">
  <form novalidate>
    First Name:<br>
    <input ng-change="myFunc()" type="text" ng-model="user.firstName" id="change">
  </form>
  <p>The input field has changed {{count}} times.</p>
  <p>form = {{user}}</p>
  <p>master = {{master}}</p>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.master = {firstName:"John"};
    $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
    };
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.myFunc = function() {
        $scope.count++;
        document.getElementById("change").className += " red";
    };
    $scope.reset();
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle:-

https://jsfiddle.net/jve3x6Lk/1/